# MySQL Callable statement in Java is null

Tags: java, mysql, sql, callable

When debugging this part of my program, it keeps telling my  prcProcedimientoAlmacenado (My stored procedure) is null. Here's the following piece of code, which connects the database to my code (It's a GUI interface where I put the values to be added to the database)

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int idFacultad;
    String connectionUrl= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basespro";
    Connection con = null;

try{
    CallableStatement prcProcedimientoAlmacenado=null;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con=(Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl,"root","bases13");
    //con.setAutoCommit(false);
    prcProcedimientoAlmacenado = con.prepareCall("{call addMateria(?,?,?)}");
    int i=Integer.parseInt(id_Materia.getText());
    System.out.println("   "+i);
    prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt("idMateria",i);
    prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt("idFacultad", 2);
    prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setString("nombreMateria", nombre_Materia.getText());
    prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.execute();
    con.commit();
}catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); 
}
```

The procedure is the following, but I tested it in MySQL Workbench and it does add. (To be more clear, the procedure takes 2 strings and an integer and adds it to the Table "Materia"

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `addMateria`(In idMa int, In idFa int, In     nomMa varchar(40))
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Materia(idMateria,idFacultad,nombreMateria) VALUES (idMa,idFa,nomMa);
END
```

Comment: What do you mean that it keeps telling you that `prcProcedimientoAlmacenado` is null? Are you catching a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/YJn43Gl.png  I get this when debugging, apparently my procedure is nullified when it enters to that breakpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this syntax:

```
...
prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(1,i);
prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setInt(2, 2);
prcProcedimientoAlmacenado.setString(3, nombre_Materia.getText());
...
```

To execute query that update, delete or insert any data into the database, you have to use:

```
executeUpdate(query)
```

See [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still isn't working. Same result.
http://i.imgur.com/YJn43Gl.png This is what I get.